# Autodesk Forge Viewer: Connect Fragment Material to Revit Model Data

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

EDIT: TLDR there is currently no way to know material names on the fragment level.

I want to read the materials from fragments of a node and change their materials according to a map that uses the Revit material names as keys.

I have the following "Materials and Finishes" properties from a node in the model (retrieved via Viewer3D):
[image: Node Data from "Materials and Finishes"]

And I have the following THREE materials from the fragments of that node:
[image: THREEjs Materials from Node Fragments]

Is there a way to set the names of the THREE materials to match the model data (or use them at all)?

Ideally I would be able to match these THREE materials with the following materials extracted from this node:
[image: Material Data]

Comment: It looks like a possible fix to this would be to set the name within the viewer3D source code below 'convertMaterial(_x, _x2, _x3, _x4)'. I am not sure if this is feasible, but it is something to look into @AutodeskDevs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So you are trying to rename an existing material in Forge Viewer based on certain property of a geometry this material is attached to? Can you please elaborate more on what this would be used for?

Comment: @PetrBroz I am trying to find the material names of fragments. This is being used to change the appearance of a door that is modelled as one node in the viewer.

Comment: I am able to get the fragment material, but the 'name' property is blank, so I cannot know which of my Revit materials it is.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarification. Let me respond in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVF file format (generated by the Model Derivative service and loaded by Forge Viewer) does not preserve material names unfortunately. The fragments are simply associated with a specific material based on its index in the list.

The "Materials and Finishes" data is basically just a property specific to the original file (in this case a Revit model), and it may not be available in other file formats.

EDIT: I tried looking into the *Materials.json.gz* file, and unfortunately the names are not included there, either:

```json
{
    "name": "LMVTK Simple Materials",
    "version":  "1.0",
    "scene":    {
        "SceneUnit":    8215,
        "YIsUp":    0
    },
    "materials":    {
        "0":    {
            "version":  2,
            "userassets":   ["0"],
            "materials":    {
                "0":    {
                    "tag":  "",
                    "proteinType":  "",
                    "definition":   "SimplePhong",
                    "properties":   {
                        "integers": {
                            "mode": 4
                        },
                        "booleans": {
                            "color_by_object":  false,
                            "generic_is_metal": false,
                            "generic_backface_cull":    true
                        },
                        "scalars":  {
                            "generic_transparency": {
                                "units":    "",
                                "values":   [0]
                            }
                        },
                        "colors":   {
                            "generic_diffuse":  {
                                "values":   [{
                                        "r":    0,
                                        "g":    1,
                                        "b":    0,
                                        "a":    1
                                    }]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "transparent":  false,
                    "textures": {
                }
                }
            }
        },
        "1":    {
            "version":  2,
            "userassets":   ["0"],
            "materials":    {
                "0":    {
                    "tag":  "",
                    "proteinType":  "",
                    "definition":   "SimplePhong",
                    "properties":   {
                        "integers": {
                            "mode": 4
                        },
                        "booleans": {
                            "color_by_object":  false,
                            "generic_is_metal": false,
                            "generic_backface_cull":    true
                        },
                        "scalars":  {
                            "generic_transparency": {
                                "units":    "",
                                "values":   [0]
                            }
                        },
                        "colors":   {
                            "generic_diffuse":  {
                                "values":   [{
                                        "r":    0.400000,
                                        "g":    0.400000,
                                        "b":    0.400000,
                                        "a":    1
                                    }]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "transparent":  false,
                    "textures": {
                }
                }
            }
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. So if I understand this correctly, fragment 0 would be glass (material 0 from Revit)?

Comment: Well, the only information you'll be able to find out is that fragment X is connected to material Y, but you won't be able to see whether material Y is "Ext Door - Panel", "Glass", or any other one.

Comment: Btw. you can try peeking into the material lists that are downloaded by the viewer for a given model (the file is typically called something like _Materials.json.gz_ or _ProteinMaterials.json.gz_) to see if perhaps there's any additional information there but again, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Ah yeah I tried the fragment indexing approach and it looks like the fragment indexes of the node are not in the same order as Revit material indexes.

Comment: Also I am having a hard time finding this materials list file. Any tips?

Comment: Side note: Does an SVF2 translation also have these limitations?

Comment: You can experiment with the SVF assets in various ways. If you use Visual Studio Code, try the [Forge Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) extension - it allows you to download the SVF assets of a specific design. Or use the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) Node.js library to download the SVF assets from command-line.

Comment: Regarding SVF2: that format is basically created by post-processing SVF(1), so the material names won't be there, either.